# Woocommerce checkout page takes 9 to 10 seconds to respond

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am running a woocommerce store, everything works fine except the checkout page response. I found that it calls a request for `admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_checkout` and after getting the response it transfers to thank you page.

Does shifting to VPS will do or there are any other ways we can speed up this process? Because currently it takes approx 10 seconds which is frustrating for the users.

I googled it but couldn't find anything useful regarding the same.

Comment: removed unnecessary words

Comment: @demonplus thanks for making it clean

Comment: Check the function if there is any pause etc in it, else this is probably a hosting / vps issue

Comment: same problem here...